# Conditional implementation of a trait in Rust

Tags: rust, traits

Is it possible to conditionally implement a trait in Rust, in a way that is equivalent to the following pseudocode?

```rust
trait MyTrait {
   fn my_trait(&self) -> u32;
}

impl<T> MyTrait for T where T: SomeTrait1 {
   fn my_trait(&self) -> u32 {
       1
   }
} else where T: SomeTrait2 {
   fn my_trait(&self) -> u32 {
       2
   }
} else {
   fn my_trait(&self) -> u32 {
       0
   }
}
```

How can this be implemented using stable Rust and/or in nightly with the upcoming specialization RFCs?

Comment: I don't think so - it would require some kind of negative trait bounds, which are highly unstable and it's unsure if they will ever be stable because they fundamentally collide with some of the basic concepts of Rust.

Comment: With macros, maybe? You can't do this at run-time like in Ruby or Python. Do these traits overlap, or are they mutually exclusive?

Comment: Well, my interpretation of the pseudocode would be that even if `SomeTrait1` and `SomeTrait2` overlap, `SomeTrait1` would have priority, i.e., in the same way that the first condition in an if-else statement has the first condition checked first.

Comment: There is absolutely no priority for traits in Rust like there is in other languages with inheritance. It's either implemented or not, and if you have overlap you have "conflicting implementations".

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```rust
#![feature(specialization)]

trait MyTrait {
    fn my_trait(&self) -> u32;
}

trait SomeTrait1 {}
trait SomeTrait2 {}

trait HasTrait1 {
    const HAS_TRAIT_1: bool;
}

impl<T> HasTrait1 for T {
    default const HAS_TRAIT_1: bool = false;
}

impl<T: SomeTrait1> HasTrait1 for T {
    const HAS_TRAIT_1: bool = true;
}

trait HasTrait2 {
    const HAS_TRAIT_2: bool;
}

impl<T> HasTrait2 for T {
    default const HAS_TRAIT_2: bool = false;
}

impl<T: SomeTrait2> HasTrait2 for T {
    const HAS_TRAIT_2: bool = true;
}

impl<T> MyTrait for T {
    fn my_trait(&self) -> u32 {
        if T::HAS_TRAIT_1 {
            1
        } else if T::HAS_TRAIT_2 {
            2
        } else {
            0
        }
    }
}

impl SomeTrait1 for u16 {}
impl SomeTrait2 for u32 {}

fn main() {
    dbg!(1u8.my_trait());
    dbg!(1u16.my_trait());
    dbg!(1u32.my_trait());
}
```

But it requires the `specialization` feature which is incomplete. There is the `min_specialization` feature, but I don't know how to use it and I don't know whether it works with this code.

Comment: Incomplete and unsound (though I haven't checked if the unsoundess applies to this case).

Comment: I also found a way to [implement this with `min_specialization`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1520460990e8d6b59a48609cbdd22578) but its probably best to avoid having to implement this at all.